# Daily download counter in Grafana using SNMP

Tags: snmp, grafana, influxdb

I want to monitor daily incoming traffic on specific interface on my Cisco ASA using Grafana with InfluxDB and telegraf (snmp).

I'm using following query to get current data from ASA for my graphs:

```
SELECT derivative(mean("ifHCInOctets"), 1s) *8 AS "In", derivative(mean("ifHCOutOctets"), 1s) *8 AS "Out" FROM "snmp" WHERE ("hostname" = 'asa-01' AND "ifName" = 'WAN') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval), "ifName" fill(null)
```

How can I rebuild this query to get daily (resetting at 0:00h) download rate in singlestat module? Something like "Today we downloaded: X Gb".

I tried:

```
SELECT DIFFERENCE(LAST("ifHCInOctets")) FROM "snmp" WHERE ("hostname" = 'asa-01' AND "ifName" = 'WAN') AND $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval)
```

But I don't know how to get proper time period and I'm not sure if *bits* are a good unit for presenting this data or should I multiply result by 8?

Or maybe there's better way or different OID to measure this kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SPREAD function](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/functions/#spread) and calculate it on the InfluxDB level:

```
SELECT 
  SPREAD("ifHCInOctets")*8 AS "In", 
  SPREAD("ifHCOutOctets")*8 AS "Out" 
FROM "snmp" 
WHERE 
  "hostname" = 'asa-01' AND "ifName" = 'WAN' AND $timeFilter
```

Override relative time (`now/d`) in the single stat panel and display current value.